# Absolute Error in dB in a Measurement

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I was reading [this material](http://arpg-serv.ing2.uniroma1.it/mostacci/didattica/lab-elettronica-I/LezioneBB_incertezza/04_UNCERTAINTY_2019.pdf) about doing measurements and I have seen this expression for the absolute error in dB:

$$a_x\text{(dB)}=20\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{a_x\text{(%)}}{100}\right) $$

My question is: why is there the term $+ 1$? I know that to convert a certain quantity $X$ in dB, we should do $20 log (x)$, not $20 log (1 + x)$.

Then I have another question: what if for instance $X$ is measured in 1/m (meter$^{-1}$)? I have seen something like dBm$^{-1}$, but what does it mean? In theory, there would be a term like $20 log (m^{-1})$, and I do not know the meaning of the logarithm of a unit of measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is the measurement and $\delta a$ its error (in the same units as $a$):
$$
a(\text{dB})+a_x(\text{dB})=20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{a+\delta a}{a_0}\right)=20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{a}{a_0}\left(1+\frac{\delta a}{a}\right)\right)$$$$=20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{a}{a_0}\right)+20 \log_{10}\left(1+\frac{\delta a}{a}\right).
$$

Then, since $\delta a/a$ is the relative error,
$$
a_x(\text{dB}) =20 \log_{10}\left(1+ \frac{a_x(\%)}{100}\right).
$$

Comment: Excuse me, I do not understand the first step: why is the sum of a and ax (which should be the true value of the measurement, correct?) equal to the expression at right?

Comment: You are trying to convert the measurement $a+\delta a$ into something measured in dB plus an error measured in dB. You can read it also starting from the second step. You are converting what you measured in dB. It turns out it is $a$ (without the error) expressed in dB plus another term, which is due to the error. You call this last term the "error expressed in dB".

Comment: And what does a0 represent?

Comment: In the definition of dB there is a reference value to which calculate the logarithm (the dB is the log of a ratio). For instance in acoustics as reference value is often used the threshold of human hearing.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much